# Accessing a static -kind of field of a of the class of an instance in c#

Tags: c#

Sorry for asking such a simple question, but I haven't yet found an answer by searching.

So, is it possible, in c#, to access a field (value of which doesn't need to change) of a class through both an instance of the class and as you would access a static field of the class using the name of the class?

For example if I have

```
public class Myclass
{
    public int a = 0;
}
```

I want to do elsewhere in the code, in another class

```
Myclass instance = new Myclass();
int b = instance.a;
```

and

```
int c = Myclass.a;
```

Making int a static or const doesn't help, is there any way to do this? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: So are you trying to statically access an instance field, in which case, which instances values do you want, or do you want to access a static field through an instance, in which case, why do you need to do that instead of accessing it through the class directly?

Comment: How about preprocessor directives, can't they be accessed if you need it through out?

Comment: I want to access a static field using an instance. This is because I have ~15 classes that have same kinds of static fields and I would like to make the code simpler by handling all the classes in the same way, maybe even without duplicating the code for different classes by creating a var instance

Answer (score 0):

If `MyClass` were a Singleton then yes, you could do this, but in your scenario it appears that's going to be a no because you're instantiating it elsewhere. See, if `MyClass` were a Singleton you could do something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass _instance = new MyClass();

    public static MyClass Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public static int a { get { return _instance.A; } }

    private MyClass() { }
}
```

but as you can see it's really **hacky.** You are really mixing OO concepts here. There is a distinct difference between accessing a `static` value - `MyClass.a` - and an instance value. Just deal with creating the instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  You cannot access an instance field without an instance of the type, and you can't access a static field through an instance of the type in C#, you need to access it through the type itself.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. May be you need to change the way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this, because:

(1) The language prevents you from accessing a static field via an instance reference, and

(2) You cannot have two fields with the same name. (So you can't have a static and a nonstatic field with the same name.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a good idea, but still, you might be able to do it like this

```
class Class1
{
    public static int staticBlah = 0;

    public int blah { 
        get{return Class1.staticBlah;} 
        set{Class1.staticBlah = value;} 
    }


}
```

Of course, you're not using *exactly* the same name but you'd be accessing the same variable.